# Where returns WhereListIterator in which Current is Null

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a query to DB using EntityFramework like that:

```
var result = this.UnitOfWork.PatientProductGiveRepository.Find(x =>
        x.ProductGroupId == pgId &&
        (
            x.ModificationDate != null && DateTime.Compare(x.ModificationDate.Value, lastTime) > 0 ||
            DateTime.Compare(x.CreationDate, lastTime) > 0
        ))
    .Result;
```

a line below I am trying to select only few rows that match my datetime needs:

```
var result2 = result.Where(x =>
    0 <= x.GiveDate.Subtract(curTime).TotalHours &&
    x.GiveDate.Subtract(curTime).TotalHours < 24);
```

Unfortunately result2 is `{System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereListIterator<LMS.Common.DataAccess.PatientProductGive>}` with `Current: null`.
Although when I put a breakpoint after result 2 and I run `result.Where(x => 0 <= x.GiveDate.Subtract(curTime).TotalHours && x.GiveDate.Subtract(curTime).TotalHours < 24)` in VS2015 watch it actually returns three elements that I need.

Why isn't it working in the code?

Answer (score 2):

`Current` is null on any newly created iterator for a reference type. More generally, for an iterator for any type `T`, `Current` will initially equal `default(T)` before the first time its `MoveNext()` method is called (or after `Reset()` is called). You've probably never called `MoveNext()` directly, but that's what happens behind the scenes when you start enumerating an iterator with a `foreach` loop. Calling `ToList()` on a LINQ query will have the same effect, most likely because somewhere in there, there's a `foreach` loop.

And for any reference type `T`, `default(T)` is `null`.

Try iterating over it:

```
foreach (var x in result2) {
    //  Stuff
}
```

Your LINQ query is "lazy": `result2` is not a collection of results. It is an iterator which will produce results as you request them. As the name suggests, `System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereListIterator<T>` is not a collection type. But even if it were, an enumerator for that collection would still not have a current item until you start enumerating it:

```
var items = new System.Collections.Generic.List<string> { "one", "two" };
var enumerator = items.GetEnumerator();
Console.WriteLine(enumerator.Current ?? "null");
```

Output:

> null

[Here's a fiddle:](https://dotnetfiddle.net/cIvbQ5)

```
public static void Main()
{
    var x = Enumerable.Range(0, 4).Select(n => "Item " + n);
    var current = ((System.Collections.IEnumerator)x).Current;

    //  It is an absolute certainty that this iterator will return items.
    Console.WriteLine("Current == {0}", current == null ? "(null)" : current.ToString());

    foreach (var y in x)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Next Item: {0}", y);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Current == (null)
Next Item: Item 0
Next Item: Item 1
Next Item: Item 2
Next Item: Item 3
```

Comment: You mean reference type, not value type, in first paragraph.

Comment: @Evk Ulp. Thanks!